# Twitter product card next steps after validation

Tags: twitter, shopify, product

Looking to set up a Twitter product card integrated through Shopify -- while the product info is populating in the validator preview and the got confirmation that the card was approved, there is no next step available. The help article that shopify provided instructs to use "catalog view" as next step however I haven't been able to access. Any insights? 
https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/social-media/twitter/taking-advantage-of-twitter-cards

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you're already able to view the proper card in the validator tool, then all that's left is to tweet out a link and see if it works!

--

It looks like Twitter has changed their Card Application & Validation pages since that Shopify article was written.

According to https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/product, just copy and paste this code into your twitter-card snippet, and update it with your information.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="product">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@iHeartRadio">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@iHeartRadio">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="iheart.com">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="24/7 Beatles — Celebrating 50 years of Beatlemania">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://radioedit.iheart.com/service/img/nop()/assets/images/05fbb21d-e5c6-4dfc-af2b-b1056e82a745.png">
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="Genre">
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="Classic Rock">
<meta name="twitter:label2" content="Location">
<meta name="twitter:data2" content="National">
```

Once you've done that, you can go back to the Validator Page (https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) to check that everything works the way it should.